# Users on Chrome OS cannot view .csv or .xls file opened in new tab

Tags: java, google-chrome, export-to-csv

We have a simple link that serves up a downloadable version of a report in .pdf, .csv, and .xls formats. Recently, the .csv and .xls options have stopped working for our chromebook users while the .pdf version continues to work as intended. Where the link used to prompt the user for a download, or open in a new tab, it now does nothing. The only workaround other than using a different OS is the following:

Before you go to click "View" to download the link:

1. Right click on the page and select "Inspect" or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> i to open the developer tools
2. On the new screen select the "Console" tab at the top
3. Click the "View" link to see the report like before
4. You should notice a warning message in the console at this point
5. Right click on the link in that warning message
6. Select open in new tab
7. The document should open in Google Sheets

The link in the warning message described in the list is a warning thrown by Chrome browser.

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv:
```

We've released this workaround to our support users, but obviously can't ask clients to use the developer tools to download their file. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. It should be noted that this problem is only for our Chrome OS users, and not any other users on the Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble inspecting on the current version (Chrome OS) hi-light this javascript code and drag it to your Chrome bookmarks bar:

```
javascript:alert("Inspect Element On");javascript:document.body.contentEditable = 'true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0;javascript:alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```